# What does the copyright() method in python do?

Tags: python, copyright-display

I have seen PyCharm suggest to me to use a function named `copyright()`. I have never written such function / imported anything which means it is a python standard library function. could not find any docs about it neither description in PyCharm itself. The function don't have any arguments which seems odd as I would infer it's goal is to set some part of code to be copyrighted. What is this function for and how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copyright()` is a Python builtin class.
You can CTRL + click on the function name in Pycharm so it will lead you to the actual source definition, which should belong to your standard python installation.

The function will print the actual Python copyright, which is contained in `sys.copyright`

It's the same as `credits` function